# DELL 7530 NVidia Graphic Card not working in Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

After i finished installed ubuntu 16.04.4. Im not able to start ubuntu. 
I used the "nomodeset" method. Then i'm able to start ubuntu and login.
I tried to connect my laptop to extend monitor thru HDMI. however, it not able to detect the monitor.
How can i install nvidia driver? When i tried. i go into the loop-logon problem.
do i need to remove the "nomodeset" after nvidia driver is installed?
My Graphic card is Nvidia Qurodo P2000.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Ubuntu have just updated the kernel version from 4.14 to 4.15. With the upgrade the issue is solved.

For newly installed Ubuntu, ensure that u enable the update option during installing. This will ensure that yr kernel is 4.15.

After installation, on the 1st reboot, wait for the grub screen to appear. 
Now enter E at the Ubuntu option. Use the "nomodeset" method. (google "dell nomodeset"). Use method 1 only. This will allow u to login without problem.

Once inside ubuntu, google "Ubuntu Nvidia Drivers", follows the step to install Nvidia driver. Select the Nvidia driver in via "additional drivers".
reboot the system.

That all.